# TinyMCE templates don't work

Tags: json, tinymce, angular-ui

I've configured TinyMCE editor as described in [the documentation](https://www.tinymce.com/docs/plugins/template/#templates).

```
$scope.tinymceOptions = {
    plugins: 'template',
    templates: '/rest/templates'
}
```

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/rest/templates", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE})
@ResponseBody
public Set<TemplateVO> getTemplates() {
    Set<TemplateVO> result = // ...
    return result;
}
```

As you can see, in `templates` option I've specified an URL that produces a list of templates. When a user executes 'Insert template' command, the controller method `getTemplates()` is invoked, and all templates are returned in a JSON array.

```
[{"title":"test","description":"test","content":"test"},{"title":"test 2","description":"test","content":"test 2"}]
```

And I expect them to be displayed. But I receive a message with text 'No templates defined'.

When I specify the same items as an object, template insertion is working fine:

```
$scope.tinymceOptions = {
    plugins: 'template',
    templates: [
        {title: 'test', description: 'test', content: 'test'},
        {title: 'test 2', description: 'test', content: 'test 2'}
    ]
}
```

What is the correct way of loading TinyMCE templates from remote URL?

**UPD.** I've caugth an exception inside `JSON.parse()` (in Google Chrome)

> EvalError: Refused to evaluate a string as JavaScript because `'unsafe-eval'` is not an allowed source of script in the following Content Security Policy directive: `"script-src 'self'"`. at `eval` (native) at `Object.parse` ...

Comment: Which version do you you use? Check http://community.tinymce.com/forum/viewtopic.php?id=32825

Comment: @BasvanStein I use TinyMCE 4.2.8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your [Content Security Policy](http://content-security-policy.com/) does not allow JS evaluation, because it is unsafe. You can add `'unsafe-eval'` to your CSP and templates loading will work:

```
<!-- Chrome 25+; FireFox 23+; Safari 7+ -->
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval'"/>
<!-- FireFox 4+; IE 10+ (not fully) -->
<meta http-equiv="X-Content-Security-Policy" content="xhr-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval'"/>
<!-- Chrome 14+; Safari 6+ -->
<meta http-equiv="X-WebKit-CSP" content="script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval'"/>
```